# ActionListener Anonymous class between two JPanel

Tags: java, swing, button, jpanel, actionlistener

I'm trying to get to panels to work with each other RECURSIVELY.

When I'm on the main GUI I have the first JPanel with a Button Add Client,
Once clicked it brings me to the JPanel with a Form and then I recuperate those values, 
and send them away in a JTable in the first JPanel the Main GUI.

When I then try to insert a second record. I get a blank GUI. I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong. How can I implement multiple time the same action to repeat ? Which is Load up the form, enter the information, push it on the Table, and the process repeats as much as I need it.

This is the Add Client button declaration in the MAIN GUI

```
Button btn_AddClient = new Button("Add Client");
        btn_AddClient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.setVisible(false);
                contentPane.setVisible(false);
                setContentPane(contentPaneClient);
            }
        });
        btn_AddClient.setBounds(259, 12, 70, 22);
        contentPane.add(btn_AddClient);
```

This is the Add Button of the Form in the second Panel

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                setContentPane(contentPaneClient);
                panel.setVisible(true);
                contentPane.setVisible(true);
                contentPaneClient.setVisible(false);
                LigneJTab l = new LigneJTab(textFieldPrenomClient.getText(),textFieldNomClient.getText(), textFieldAdresseClient.getText(), chckbxHomme.isSelected(), Sport.FOOTBALL);
                myModel.addLine(l);
                setContentPane(contentPane);
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setBounds(263, 40, 117, 29);
        contentPaneClient.add(btnAdd);
```

Comment: 1- I'd be very careful about mixing AWT and Swing components (`Button` and `JButton`), 2- Avoid using `setBounds`, use appropriate layout managers, 3- Take a look at [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which will make swapping between different views considerably simpler, 4- Try providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as code snippets don't provide enough context

Comment: Will look into SSCCE as this is one of my first posts in Java. Why is mixing AWT and Swing a bad idea ?

Comment: The code is too long to provide an SSCCE, and it's contains a few other classes.

Comment: I upload the current Application as a runnable JAR File so you could see what is going on. http://www.4shared.com/file/13-k02C1/gestionClient.html

Comment: We don't care about what it's doing, we care about how it's doing it.  A runnable jar is both useless and a security risk which I doubt any one here would be willing to download and run

Comment: AWT and Swing use different rendering techniques to paint there components and they tend to not like playing together.  If your code won't fit.  Break it down to a runnable example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Here is a Pastebin of only the GUI, the other classes have not been pasted in just to make it shorter. http://pastebin.com/DGWC7hHw

Comment: I suspect that the `null` manager is doing you no favors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //setContentPane(contentPaneClient);
            //panel.setVisible(true);
            //contentPane.setVisible(true);
            //contentPaneClient.setVisible(false);

            LigneJTab l = new LigneJTab(textFieldPrenomClient.getText(),textFieldNomClient.getText(), textFieldAdresseClient.getText(), chckbxHomme.isSelected(), Sport.FOOTBALL);
            myModel.addLine(l);

            panel.setVisible(true);
            contentPane.setVisible(true);
            setContentPane(contentPane);

        }
    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(263, 40, 117, 29);
    contentPaneClient.add(btnAdd);
```

Commented the top part and added the `setContentPane(contentPane);` and that worked !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: You don't need to swap out the content panes to ask for data. A much more elegant way is using a modal dialog box. To make one, first create a dialog class:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public MyDialog(Frame parent) {
        super(parent);
        setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        // add components to getContentPane()
        // to close dialog, use setVisible(false) in listeners
    }

    public OutputData getData() {
        OutputData data = new OutputData();
        show();
        // show only returns after a setVisible(false)
        data.field = textField.getText();
        // for example, repeat as many times as necessary
        return data;
    }
}
```

To invoke this dialog from the `JFrame`, use the following code:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);
OutputData data = dialog.getData()
// now retrieve fields from data
```

Comment: Wow that looks interesting ... its hard to follow how everything works coming from a javascript background where everything isn't typed and so procedural .... java is completely object oriented and its hard to follow all these classes and how many to do .... all the adapters and terms like generic classes .... subclasses or inside classes ...  I find it hard to follow variable like .... Context context ..... parent ... this .. differences between interface and abstract classes ....  any recommendations for good sites for extremely slow beginners ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get red all over the place. What am I not doing right ?http://pastebin.com/LPYztq7Z

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. I don't know why this isn't working, but I may have an update to this.

Comment: Update: You should regard this as a template which directs you to fill in the point explained in the comments. you also need to define the `OutputData` class.